# Eclipse: How to export local history to a real SCM system like Git or SVN

Tags: eclipse, git, export, history, local

I have an **Eclipse** project which started out as a smallish, quick'n'dirty, private hack. I did not bother to use a real SCM (source code management) system like Git or SVN, not even locally. What I have instead is a few days' worth of **Local History**, an out-of-the-box Eclipse feature. As so often, the project grew and I want to **share it including history,** because the history shows a lot of refactoring steps which come in handy as a showcase in order to teach someone else about refactoring, clean code etc.

I already know that I can manually retrieve old versions file by file and manually migrate them to e.g. a Git repository, committing changes one by one and file by file. But what I am really interested in is:

- Can I reset the whole project (not just a single file) to a certain date using Local History?
- Is there a way to export certain (or all) snapshots of the local project history, so I can commit them to Git snapshot by snapshot?
- Is there even an option (or an external tool, script etc.) by means of which I can automatically migrate a project's local history to a real SCM system like Git (preferred) or SVN? It would also be okay if the tool just created lots of full project snapshots in subfolders named by timestamps.

Disclaimer: Yes, I do know that I should have used Git right from the start. It would have cost me just three minutes to set up a local repository etc. But... BUT. You know. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is, but keep in mind that the task shouldn't be too tedious.

Make a copy of your project before starting, just for safety's sake and then:

```
git init
(revert to snapshot 1)
git add .
git commit -m "First snapshot commit"
(revert to snapshot 2)
git add .
git commit -m "Second snapshot commit"
```

Wash, rinse, repeat.

If you've only got a few dozen snapshots, it shouldn't take more than an hour or so to do, which is probably a lot less than it would take to figure out a programmatic solution.

Comment: As I said, I know I can do it manually, but with the additional burden that there is no such thing as snapshots per project, only per file, so I always have to check (n) file histories if (n) is the total number of files in my local repository. Too bad, but I was not very optimistic from the start...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer is "no" to all of your questions. At least, using standard built-in Eclipse functionality; there's always a chance that someone has written a plugin that meets your needs, but in this case I'd be surprised. Check the Eclipse Marketplace (found under the `Help` menu).